# limit output of control categorical variable R

Tags: r, lm, categorical-data

I have a categorical variable with more than 15 categories. When I use it in regression:

```
Reg <- lm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + Category, data = mydata)
```

It creates a dummy for each category which is perfectly what I want, but I don't want to see each dummy in my output when I use:

```
summary(Reg)
```

Is there a way to just see 'Category' as one variable in output? I have another categorical variable with 135 categories...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this.
 I've used the iris data to fit a linear model:

```
 lm_mod<-lm(Petal.Length~Sepal.Length+Species,data=iris)
```

Then you can choose a specific variable as follows:

```
summary(lm_mod$model$Petal.Length)
```

**EDIT**: Do you really need to call summary?

Comment: I use 'stargazer' package to create a table of regression results. What happens is I get 15 rows for this categorical variable which is very annoying...